# How to pass data from one ViewController to another after using Segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I went from one ViewController to another using Segue in my second viewController has an UITableView. now, I want to push from second ViewController's didSelected method to another viewController.

code use to Segue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;

SearchVC *svc = segue.destinationViewController;
self.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = YES;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
}
```

under button action:

```
-(void) searchButtonClicked:(id)sender {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"search" sender:nil];
}
```

And the main problem arise here, can't navigate using below code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  PackageListVC *pdvc = (PackageListVC *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PackageListVC"];

  pdvc.strServiceProviderId = [[[arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ServiceProviderId"] stringValue];
  pdvc.strCategoryId = [[[arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CategoryId"] stringValue];
  pdvc.strSubCategoryId = [[[arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SubCategoryId"] stringValue];
  pdvc.strTitle = [[arrSearch objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"CompanyName"];

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:pdvc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: what is your question ? How to pass data  using segues or navigation issue you are having ?

Comment: Put `SearchVC` in `UINavigationController`

Comment: Check this topic
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You do it in the `prepareForSegue` method.

where you declare svc (`SearchVC *svc = segue.destinationViewController;`) you can say something like:

```
 svc.variable = 1;
```